# WPF Click Once using 2 development computers on Git Hub

Tags: github, clickonce

For an unsigned WPF click once app:

I want to start using 2 different computers, one at home and one at the office. My code will be on GitHub and I'll push/pull to keep the 2 computers in sync.

- I publish from computer A and an user installs the program.
- I then I update and publish from computer B to the same web location.

Will the B changes be viewed as an update or will the click once fail because the changes came from a different computer than the original install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickOnce determines if it should download the update based on the publish version, which is different from your actual assembly versions. As long as Computer B publishes to the same update location, clients will download it as an update as long as the publish version has been incremented. Conversely, if Computer B doesn't increment the publish version, clients won't download the update even if the code is different. Here's some documentation around the publish version and how to set/change it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haeyaeba.aspx.